# Baking best practice resources?

Tags: baking

Could someone offer some good resources regarding best practices when setting up a baking operation in Tezos ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How to Delegate Tezos XTZ with Tezos Client and Running Your Own Node (Betanet) - with Mac OS
https://medium.com/cryptium/how-to-delegate-tezos-xtz-with-tezos-client-and-running-your-own-node-betanet-cea6960cf45

Build a Betanet node on Debian 9
https://github.com/tezoscommunity/FAQ/wiki/Build-a-Betanet-node-on-Debian-9

Tezos Baking Economics — Guide
https://medium.com/figment-networks/tezos-baking-economics-guide-5d4a2bc2a9d3

Tezos baking howto
https://gist.github.com/dakk/bdf6efe42ae920acc660b20080a506dd

Tezos Installation Guide - On Ubuntu with VirtualBox
https://medium.com/coinmonks/tezos-installation-guide-8175b3f0b748

Setting Up a Secure Baker
https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/setting-up-a-secure-baker-27bb12363679

Preparing for betanet launch with Nix and Ledger Nano S
https://gist.github.com/et4te/1c94c9a072ececf15bdcf4d21e743bb6

Building and running Tezos betanet
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QWZrBwCFhTqlKziI5mZxY5dUFBrjga0TtJ3iwd5BC8k/edit#

Checkout mainnet instead of "betanet", the rest remains the same
https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQyOC5P24FJKPACRrhUpcmwvovhPlp4TWGgtLwdxB8YGoKt4YtvdvRU83fP2ps2g5t84UUfKIQTgBjY/pub

BambouClub's Tezos rewards calculation sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTOyZxHRyCFuGEc3HjZWp3EkWPVJFVZNqPkxhsnHf1pE4XFuqFf2lNe79rSDfjkSaU3Bv_TAE1hcAFZ/pubhtml#

Tezos baking tools to ease a bakers life
Focus on uptime and ease of use / monitoring
https://github.com/etomknudsen/tezos-baking

Nautilus provides a set of resilient and globally-distributed blockchain deployments. (Not ready yet, but will set the standard once ready!)
https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Nautilus/wiki

Answer (score 5):

From obsidian systems:

https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos/blob/master/README.md

Tezos gitlab docs

https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/index.html

Baking tools

https://github.com/etomknudsen/tezos-baking/blob/master/README.md